# Opening Designer on a new Custom Control causes "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In WinForms, c#, I create a new Custom Control through Project > Add Component > Custom Control (Windows Forms).
The designer for my new Control opens, with the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
Is there something I have not set up correctly?

Call Stack:
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.Sessions.InitializeRootComponentHandler.HandleRequest(InitializeRootComponentRequest request)
at
Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.RequestHandler`2.Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.IRequestHandler.HandleRequest(Request request)

Designer.cs -

```
    partial class BKSlide2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Class Code -

```
    public partial class BKSlide2 : Control
    {
        public BKSlide2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
```

.resx has no items in it.

All this is auto generated, yet it still fails.
I have tried taking out the InitializeComponent, and the OnPaint method.  No improvement.
How can I get the designer to behave?

Comment: Did you rebuild the Project before trying to add the new Control to a Form? Assuming that's the *designer* you're referring to. If you instead want to design your Control, then build a UserControl, which has its own designer

Comment: I can design and build the control, and it works well.  I can add it to main form, where it appears correctly.
Is Designer not applicable to Custom Controls?

Comment: Do you mean, in a .Net 6 Project, the first time you create a Custom Control, you receive that exception because VS tries to open the Control's Designer, but it fails because a Custom Control doesn't have one? Just close that tab and rebuild the Project -- Note that *Designer* here doesn't refer to the `.designer.cs` file, but to a visual Designer surface, similar to the Designer of a Form or UserControl

Comment: Controls (classes derived from `Control`) don't have a Designer you can interact with. As mentioned, if you need a Designer surface, build a UserControl instead of a Custom Control

Comment: Still errors to open the designer surface in the tab (right clicking in code - View Designer.
I added a new Custom Control.  Closed the errored design tab.  Rebuilt project.  Opened with right click - View Designer.

Comment: OK.  That's what I was wondering.  It's not available for the Custom Control.  Thanks @Jimi.